# integer solution to an equation - do solutions exist?

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

prove or find a counterexample: The equation $x^n + y^n = z^n$, where $n$  is a natural number, has no solutions at all where $x, y,z$ are integer.

counterexample: if $n=3$ and $x=1$ and $y=2$ and  $z=3$ then
$$1^3 + 2^3 = 3^3$$
$$1 + 8 = 27$$
$9$ is not equal to $27$

Is this right??need help...

Comment: You only need one counterexample to show that a theorem is *not* true. Your counterxample disproves the following theorem: if $x$, $y$ and $z$ are integers and $n$ is an integer with $n \ge 3$, then $x^n + y^n = z^n$.

Comment: I changed your highly uninformative title for the question.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious counterexample is: $X=Y=Z=0$. And your approach isn't correct since I could argue that you only proved that $(1,2,3)$ for $n=3$ is not a solution and that there may exist some solution. A counter example would not look for examples in accordance with the original statement, but ones that contradict it, like the one I gave you at first.

Answer (score 0):

Think carefully about what it is you want to prove. From what you posted it is not clear what the counter example you give is for. To give a counter example to the given claim, you need to give a value for $n$ with $n\ge 3$, and then show that integer solutions for the equations do exist, but telling us precisely what these values of $X,Y,Z$ are. The answer is already given to you by the other comments/answers. My answer is trying to explain to you what you need to do and how need to present your answer.